# signature_invalid:Failed to validate signature

Tags: oauth

I'm using OAuth for rails and when I'm trying to POST a contact to xero, this happens:

> Xeroizer::OAuth::UnknownError in XeroController#sample
>   signature_invalid:Failed to validate signature

Comment: Take a look at [documentation](http://developer.xero.com/api-overview/oauth-issues/#signature_invalid).

Answer (score 2):

This could be relevant: http://answers.xero.com/developer/question/25801/.  The OAuth library used by Xero isn't correctly validating oauth signatures when querystring parameters start with uppercase letters.